# search multiple float columns in pandas and return the result in a new column of the value that is the closest match

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

#default scrap time frame is 12 hours and anytime date range.

url = 'https://www.betexplorer.com/odds-movements/soccer/'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content)
matches = soup.find_all("td", class_="table-main__tt")
best_odds = soup.find_all("td",class_ ="bestbet-odd")
BestOddsBookie = soup.find_all("td",class_ ="bestbet-logo")

data = []
for m in soup.select('#odds-movements tr:has(.table-main__tt)'):
    data.append({
        'match':m.a.text,
        'time':m.span.text,
        'odds':[o.get('data-odd') for o in m.select('a[data-odd]')],
        'bestOddsBookie':[m.get('title') for m in BestOddsBookie]
    })

best_odds = [m.get('data-odd') for m in best_odds]
bookieTitles = [m.get('title') for m in BestOddsBookie]

urls = []
for match in matches:
    link = 'https://www.betexplorer.com' + match.a.get('href')
    urls.append(link)

data = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['match','time','odds','BestOdds','BestOddsBookie'])
data['BestOdds'] = best_odds
data['BestOdds'] = data['BestOdds'].astype(float)
data['BestOddsBookie'] = bookieTitles
data['odds'] = data['odds'].apply(lambda x: list(pd.unique(x)))
data['HomeOdds'] = data.odds.apply(lambda x: x[0]).astype(float)
data['DrawOdds'] = data.odds.apply(lambda x: x[1]).astype(float)
data['AwayOdds'] = data.odds.apply(lambda x: x[2]).astype(float)
data['url'] = urls
data['Home%'] = 1/data['HomeOdds']
data['Draw%'] = 1/data['DrawOdds']
data['Away%'] = 1/data['AwayOdds']
data['BestOdds%'] = 1/data['BestOdds']
#data['BestOddsDifference%'] = data['BestOdds'] -
data = data[['match','time','HomeOdds','DrawOdds','AwayOdds','BestOdds','Home%','Draw%','Away%','BestOdds%','BestOddsBookie','url']]
```

The above code contains the percentage value of the home/draw/away teams. I want to create a new column data['ClosestMatch'] that searches each row of the home/draw/away% win columns and subracts (with absolute) with the BestOdds% column.

The result should be the value of the closest match, I have searched many answers but none seem to work on this pandas dataframe. Essentially it is a vlookup function like in excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the dataframe you provided:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'match': ['Juventus W - Pomigliano W', 'Brusaporto - Desenzano', 'Fiorentina U19 - Verona U19', 'Yangon Utd - Rakhine United', 'West Brom - Luton', 'Eintracht Frankfurt W - Werder Bremen W', 'Gondomar - Penafiel', 'Brea - Mutilvera', 'Teplice B - Jablonec B', 'Zalaegerszegi II - Tatabanya', 'Altach U21 - Wolfurt', 'Csikszereda M. Ciuc - Metaloglobus Bucharest', 'Antoniana - Sportivo Las Parejas', 'HSL Derthona - Gozzano', 'Debrecen II - Fuzesgyarmati SK', 'Hradec Kralove B - Kolin', 'Molde 2 - Floro', 'Leviatan - Montaneses', 'Jagiellonia - Korona Kielce', 'Pero Pinheiro - Ferreiras', 'Samorin - Zilina B', 'Minaj - Dyn. Kyiv', 'EG El Palmar CF - La Union', 'Dak Lak - Long An', 'FUS Rabat - Maghreb Fez', 'Aubstadt - Bayern II', 'Xerez CD - Pozoblanco'], 'time': ['12:30', '15:00', '13:00', '11:00', '16:00', '13:01', '12:00', '16:30', '10:00', '11:00', '15:30', '10:00', '00:00', '15:00', '11:00', '10:15', '14:00', '19:00', '15:00', '16:00', '10:30', '12:00', '17:30', '10:30', '17:00', '14:00', '12:00'], 'HomeOdds': [1.03, 4.84, 1.63, 1.04, 1.87, 1.11, 9.33, 2.84, 2.26, 5.18, 1.37, 1.53, 1.39, 2.07, 3.01, 1.81, 2.1, 7.09, 1.79, 1.74, 1.38, 11.39, 3.27, 3.57, 2.16, 2.5, 1.92], 'DrawOdds': [12.44, 3.65, 3.91, 9.72, 3.53, 7.73, 5.15, 2.92, 3.58, 4.18, 5.18, 3.75, 3.88, 3.24, 3.67, 3.58, 4.38, 4.76, 3.64, 3.36, 4.48, 5.33, 3.16, 3.09, 2.76, 3.44, 3.13], 'AwayOdds': [29.44, 1.58, 4.26, 30.0, 4.03, 15.1, 1.27, 2.43, 2.44, 1.51, 5.36, 5.34, 7.07, 3.07, 1.97, 3.3, 2.42, 1.31, 4.21, 4.47, 6.11, 1.23, 2.0, 2.01, 3.56, 2.45, 3.66], 'BestOdds': [46.0, 1.6, 4.75, 41.0, 1.91, 16.29, 5.5, 3.0, 3.0, 1.62, 1.41, 5.8, 1.48, 3.4, 2.1, 2.1, 2.2, 8.0, 4.55, 4.76, 7.0, 13.58, 3.6, 3.8, 4.01, 2.53, 3.85], 'Home%': [0.970873786407767, 0.2066115702479339, 0.6134969325153374, 0.9615384615384615, 0.53475935828877, 0.9009009009009008, 0.10718113612004287, 0.35211267605633806, 0.4424778761061947, 0.19305019305019305, 0.7299270072992701, 0.6535947712418301, 0.7194244604316548, 0.48309178743961356, 0.33222591362126247, 0.5524861878453039, 0.47619047619047616, 0.14104372355430184, 0.5586592178770949, 0.5747126436781609, 0.7246376811594204, 0.08779631255487269, 0.3058103975535168, 0.2801120448179272, 0.4629629629629629, 0.4, 0.5208333333333334], 'Draw%': [0.08038585209003216, 0.273972602739726, 0.2557544757033248, 0.10288065843621398, 0.28328611898017, 0.129366106080207, 0.1941747572815534, 0.3424657534246575, 0.27932960893854747, 0.23923444976076558, 0.19305019305019305, 0.26666666666666666, 0.2577319587628866, 0.30864197530864196, 0.2724795640326976, 0.27932960893854747, 0.22831050228310504, 0.21008403361344538, 0.2747252747252747, 0.2976190476190476, 0.2232142857142857, 0.18761726078799248, 0.3164556962025316, 0.3236245954692557, 0.3623188405797102, 0.29069767441860467, 0.3194888178913738], 'Away%': [0.033967391304347824, 0.6329113924050632, 0.2347417840375587, 0.03333333333333333, 0.24813895781637715, 0.06622516556291391, 0.7874015748031495, 0.4115226337448559, 0.4098360655737705, 0.6622516556291391, 0.18656716417910446, 0.18726591760299627, 0.14144271570014144, 0.32573289902280134, 0.5076142131979695, 0.30303030303030304, 0.4132231404958678, 0.7633587786259541, 0.23752969121140144, 0.2237136465324385, 0.1636661211129296, 0.8130081300813008, 0.5, 0.49751243781094534, 0.2808988764044944, 0.4081632653061224, 0.27322404371584696], 'BestOdds%': [0.021739130434782608, 0.625, 0.21052631578947367, 0.024390243902439025, 0.5235602094240838, 0.061387354205033766, 0.18181818181818182, 0.3333333333333333, 0.3333333333333333, 0.6172839506172839, 0.7092198581560284, 0.1724137931034483, 0.6756756756756757, 0.29411764705882354, 0.47619047619047616, 0.47619047619047616, 0.45454545454545453, 0.125, 0.21978021978021978, 0.21008403361344538, 0.14285714285714285, 0.07363770250368189, 0.2777777777777778, 0.2631578947368421, 0.24937655860349128, 0.3952569169960475, 0.2597402597402597], 'BestOddsBookie': ['Betfair', 'Interwetten', 'BetVictor', 'Betfair', 'William Hill', 'Pinnacle', 'ComeOn', 'Unibet', 'Betfair', 'Betfair', '10Bet', 'Unibet', 'Unibet', 'Betway', 'Unibet', 'William Hill', 'BetVictor', 'Betfair', 'Unibet', 'Pinnacle', 'Unibet', 'Pinnacle', 'Betfair', 'Betfair', 'Pinnacle', 'Pinnacle', 'ComeOn'], 'url': ['https://www.betexplorer.com/soccer/italy/serie-a-women/juventus-pomigliano/QJ5QYNdk/', 'https://www.betexplorer.com/soccer/italy/serie-d-group-b/brusaporto-desenzano-calvina/6Nfh5QLd/', 'https://www.betexplorer.com/soccer/italy/primavera-1/fiorentina-verona/21tMntMN/', 'https://www.betexplorer.com/soccer/myanmar/national-league/yangon-united-rakhine-united/AJFE9PuB/', 'https://www.betexplorer.com/soccer/england/championship/west-brom-luton/nLI4lK3H/', 'https://www.betexplorer.com/soccer/germany/bundesliga-women/eintracht-frankfurt-werder-bremen/Y1W1OFSK/', 'https://www.betexplorer.com/soccer/portugal/taca-de-portugal/gondomar-penafiel/bFxjOfB0/', 'https://www.betexplorer.com/soccer/spain/segunda-rfef-group-2/brea-mutilvera/dKDnjACl/', 'https://www.betexplorer.com/soccer/czech-republic/cfl-group-b/teplice-jablonec/63SO9WFN/', 'https://www.betexplorer.com/soccer/hungary/nb-iii-west/zalaegerszegi-tatabanya/ttRVat7A/', 'https://www.betexplorer.com/soccer/austria/regionalliga-west-vorarlberg/altach-fc-wolfurt/KvKyrn7K/', 'https://www.betexplorer.com/soccer/romania/liga-2/miercurea-ciuc-metaloglobus-bucharest/KdD5FXNc/', 'https://www.betexplorer.com/soccer/argentina/torneo-federal/antoniana-sportivo-las-parejas/EVSCz12F/', 'https://www.betexplorer.com/soccer/italy/serie-d-group-a/hsl-derthona-gozzano/KYG0ofJO/', 'https://www.betexplorer.com/soccer/hungary/nb-iii-east/debrecen-fuzesgyarmati/KCPlF2RB/', 'https://www.betexplorer.com/soccer/czech-republic/cfl-group-b/hradec-kralove-kolin/jy4e4Awo/', 'https://www.betexplorer.com/soccer/norway/division-3-group-2/molde-floro/67hGnReE/', 'https://www.betexplorer.com/soccer/mexico/liga-premier-serie-a/leviatan-montaneses/z179xiMm/', 'https://www.betexplorer.com/soccer/poland/ekstraklasa/jagiellonia-korona-kielce/GhviXwuP/', 'https://www.betexplorer.com/soccer/portugal/taca-de-portugal/pero-pinheiro-ferreiras/4jnly26n/', 'https://www.betexplorer.com/soccer/slovakia/2-liga/samorin-zilina/UytRix9L/', 'https://www.betexplorer.com/soccer/ukraine/premier-league/minaj-dynamo-kyiv/voA6ahaQ/', 'https://www.betexplorer.com/soccer/spain/tercera-rfef-group-13/e-g-el-palmar-la-union/vkKKPPvP/', 'https://www.betexplorer.com/soccer/vietnam/v-league-2/dak-lak-long-an/WtrbcKZ9/', 'https://www.betexplorer.com/soccer/morocco/botola-pro/fus-rabat-maghreb-fez/KOPF7CuB/', 'https://www.betexplorer.com/soccer/germany/regionalliga-bayern/tsv-aubstadt-bayern/WUuFtZx2/', 'https://www.betexplorer.com/soccer/spain/tercera-rfef-group-10/xerez-cd-pozoblanco/vqiNtz7A/']})
```

Here is one way to do it:

```py
# Shorter version of the dataframe (optional step)
df = df[["match", "Home%", "Draw%", "Away%", "BestOdds%"]]

# Add new column with the closest match
df["ClosestMatch"] = df.apply(
    lambda x: min(
        abs(x["Home%"] - x["BestOdds%"]),
        abs(x["Draw%"] - x["BestOdds%"]),
        abs(x["Away%"] - x["BestOdds%"]),
    ),
    axis=1,
)
```

```py
print(df)
# Output
             match     Home%     Draw%     Away%  BestOdds%  ClosestMatch
0   Juventus W ...  0.970874  0.080386  0.033967   0.021739      0.012228
1   Brusaporto ...  0.206612  0.273973  0.632911   0.625000      0.007911
2   Fiorentina ...  0.613497  0.255754  0.234742   0.210526      0.024215
3   Yangon Utd ...  0.961538  0.102881  0.033333   0.024390      0.008943
4   West Brom -...  0.534759  0.283286  0.248139   0.523560      0.011199
5   Eintracht F...  0.900901  0.129366  0.066225   0.061387      0.004838
6   Gondomar - ...  0.107181  0.194175  0.787402   0.181818      0.012357
7   Brea - Muti...  0.352113  0.342466  0.411523   0.333333      0.009132
8   Teplice B -...  0.442478  0.279330  0.409836   0.333333      0.054004
9   Zalaegersze...  0.193050  0.239234  0.662252   0.617284      0.044968
10  Altach U21 ...  0.729927  0.193050  0.186567   0.709220      0.020707
11  Csikszereda...  0.653595  0.266667  0.187266   0.172414      0.014852
12  Antoniana -...  0.719424  0.257732  0.141443   0.675676      0.043749
13  HSL Derthon...  0.483092  0.308642  0.325733   0.294118      0.014524
14  Debrecen II...  0.332226  0.272480  0.507614   0.476190      0.031424
15  Hradec Kral...  0.552486  0.279330  0.303030   0.476190      0.076296
16  Molde 2 - F...  0.476190  0.228311  0.413223   0.454545      0.021645
17  Leviatan - ...  0.141044  0.210084  0.763359   0.125000      0.016044
18  Jagiellonia...  0.558659  0.274725  0.237530   0.219780      0.017749
19  Pero Pinhei...  0.574713  0.297619  0.223714   0.210084      0.013630
20  Samorin - Z...  0.724638  0.223214  0.163666   0.142857      0.020809
21  Minaj - Dyn...  0.087796  0.187617  0.813008   0.073638      0.014159
22  EG El Palma...  0.305810  0.316456  0.500000   0.277778      0.028033
23  Dak Lak - L...  0.280112  0.323625  0.497512   0.263158      0.016954
24  FUS Rabat -...  0.462963  0.362319  0.280899   0.249377      0.031522
25  Aubstadt - ...  0.400000  0.290698  0.408163   0.395257      0.004743
26  Xerez CD - ...  0.520833  0.319489  0.273224   0.259740      0.013484
```